# android get listview item by contextmenu

Tags: android, listview

In my application I'm register ContextMenu on `Listview` and I want to get clicked `Listview` item by context menu. For example if I have two row in list view with this structure:

```
public class StructReceiveSms{

    public int     userID;
    public String  username;
}
```

my adapter can be show username in listview. now i'm in below code can define conext menu on list view:

```
public class FragmentSmsReceiveMaster extends Fragment {

    private static final Boolean        DEBUG    = true;
    public ArrayAdapter                 adapter;
    private ArrayList<StructReceiveSms> receiveSmsArray;
        .
        .
        .
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        .
        smsView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        smsView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(smsView);
        .
        .
        .
}
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SmsMasterContextMenu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
        String listItemName = adapter.getItem(info.position) + "";

        /* GET CLICKED LISTVIEW ITEM AFTER CHOOSE CONTEXTMENU MENU ITEMS */

        Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, listItemName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now after click on context menu items I can get which clicked by user by `menuItemIndex` but I can not get which `Listview`'s items in `onContextItemSelected` function. for example ater opening context menu on first item I can get `userID` and `username` and show it. How to do this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Adapter's data list consists of `StructReceiveSms` objects, the `adapter.getItem(info.position)` call in `onContextItemSelected()` will return the list item the context menu was opened for, but it will need to be cast to the `StructReceiveSms` type. From this, you can get the `userID` and `username` you want.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    ...
    StructReceiveSms listItem = (StructReceiveSms) adapter.getItem(info.position);
    String selectedName = listItem.username;
    int selectedId = listItem.userID;
    ... 
}
```

This is assuming you've not overridden the `getItem()` method of the Adapter to return something else, but I imagine you would've shown that if you had.